unable to open andrioid studio project
So I have used the new verison of android studio to make project which works perfectly.Yet,I didn't realize that the teacher wanted me to use an old verison of android studio to make the project instead of the newest verison.Now I can't open the finished project using the old verison of the android studio.How can I open the andriod studio project using the old verison which his android-studio-2020.3.1.24-windows
I want to open the project using android-studio-2020.3.1.24-windows
